# ASP.NET LDAP Query filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I'm new to LDAP. Here's my question.

I fetch the person info with the string

```
uid=33650, ou=people,o=sea.com,o=sds
```

The items are very simple, `uid`, `name`, `title`, etc. but there's an item manager which is also an record in the LDAP directory, with format

```
manager = uid=81264, ou=people,o=sea.com,o=sds
```

Now I want to fetch the list of persons who report to a given manager.

How to fetch in C#?

Answer (score 1):

In order to search an LDAP directory using C#.NET, look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic3_lpadconn

In order to learn to construct custom ldap filters to perform your query, look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675768.aspx